# Is this the most pythonic way to create a list comprehension that only iterates through a set amount of items?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am learning APIs currently and one of the exercises was to create a list of weather IDs out of a dictionary (well, a JSON, technically) that contained this information for the next 48 hours. This list should only include the first 12 hours, however. I felt like this should be something I could do in a single list comprehension and wanted to know if this was the smart (read: friendly to a person trying to read the code) way to do it. I came up with this:

```
next_12_hours = [hour["weather"][0]["id"] for index, hour in enumerate(weather_data["hourly"]) if index < 12]
```

In this case, weather_data["hourly"] is a list of 48 dictionaries. Is this the best way to do this? More importantly, is it legible or am I just playing golf?

Comment: Is better like this: `next_12_hours = [hour["weather"][0]["id"] for hour in weather_data["hourly"][:12]]`

Comment: *"Is this the most pythonic way to create a list comprehension that only iterates through a set amount of items?"* - Not only is it not the most pythonic way, it's not even **a** way to only iterate partially. You do iterate through **all** of it, just then don't process some further.

Comment: @DaniMesejo a list slice, of course! I just knew there had to be a less round-about way. Thank you!